# How to filter entities by to-one relationship in Core Data.

Tags: core-data

In my function unit, I got an entity author's record. I need find out all books written by this author.
The Book has a relationship called belongToAuthor. How to request book records?

Can I use following NSPredicate to filter books by author relationship?

```
Author *author;
author = _author;
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSpredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY book.belongToAuthor == %@", author];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've followed the Core Data design principles, your relationship `belongToAuthor` (by the way, simply calling it `author` might be a much better name) has an inverse relationship on the `Author` class pointing the `Book`class - named something simple like `books`.

```
Book.belongToAuthor <<-> Author.books
```

With that you can simply rely on the power of Core Data and get all books written by that author by calling

```
NSSet *books = author.books;
```

Related documentation: [Core Data Programming Guide - Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)

Comment: One more question :)  I know there is a way to auto sync Table View with Core Data by NSFetchedResultsController. If I use author.books, is there any way to sync?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "auto sync".